# Paste with transparency into Adobe Photoshop 2023

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, windows

I copy an image of PNG format from the browser that has a transparent background and attempt to paste it into Photoshop, only to discover that a black background has been added.

This does not happen in other image editors like Paint.net, for example, so it doesn't seem to be my OS (Windows 10) clipboard killing it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Photoshop doesn't seem to support transparency in copy and pasted images in Windows.  The Windows clipboard does support it though, because it works in other software.  You will have to ask Adobe why.

Comment: Save to desktop then open.. don't copy/paste from a browser.

Comment: My fault for not using mac to run glorious adobe products I guess...

Comment: @LeeroyJenkins It has nothing to do with Windows though.  The fault is with Adobe.  If you do as Scott suggests, save the image first, then you can open it in Photoshop, or click and drag it into Photoshop.